# Как определить на какой класс нажимаем через getElementsByClassName JS

Tags: javascript, input

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "segoe ui light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
body{
    background: url(../image/back.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
#flex{
    display:flex;
}
#vybor{
    width: 35%;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
    
}
#price{
   padding: 1%;
   
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.ingredients{
    width: 25%;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 8%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    
    
}
#pizza{ 
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #2e5f0f;  
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: center;
    margin-left:60%;

   
}

.one{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(../image/1.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.two{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(../image/2.png);
    left: 150px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.three{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url(../image/3.png);
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.four{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(../image/4.png);
    left: 150px;
    top:150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

</head>

<body>
   
    <div id="pad"><div id="vybor">
    Выбранные элементы: 
    <ul id = "curElements">
      asdasd  
    </ul>   
    </div>
    <div id = "pizza">
    <div class="inPizza one"></div>
    <div class="inPizza two"></div>
    <div class="inPizza three"></div>
    <div class="inPizza four"></div></div>
    
    <div id="price">Цена: <span>0</span> BYR</div>
        
    </div>
    <div id = "flex">
    <div class ="ingredients base"><h2>Основа для пиццы: </h2><br>
    <input type="radio" class ="base" value="Чесночная"> Чесночная <br>
    <input type="radio" class ="base" value="Томатная"> Томатная <br>
    <input type="radio" class ="base" value="Барбекю"> Барбекю <br>
    </div>
    <div class ="ingredients"><h2>Мясная начинка:</h2><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meat" value="Колбаски гриль" onclick="addCurElement()">Колбаски гриль<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meat" value="Салями" onclick="addCurElement()">Салями<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meat" value="Ветчина" onclick="addCurElement()">Ветчина<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meat" value="Карбонат">Карбонат<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meat" value="Бекон">Бекон<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meat" value="Сервелат">Сервелат<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meat" value="Курица<">Курица<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meat" value="Телятина">Телятина<br>
    
    </div>
    <div class ="ingredients"><h2>Морская начинка:</h2><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="fish" value="Креветки">Креветки<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="fish" value="Лосось">Лосось<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="fish" value="Мидии">Мидии<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="fish" value="Кальмар">Кальмар<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="fish" value="Крабовое мясо">Крабовое мясо<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="fish" value="Тунец">Тунец<br>
    </div>
    <div class ="ingredients"><h2>Соус:</h2><br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sauce" value="Кисло-сладкий">Кисло-сладкий<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sauce" value="Барбекю">Барбекю<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sauce" value="Чесночный">Чесночный<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sauce" value="Карри">Карри<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sauce" value="Терияки">Терияки<br>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/script.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть такой html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="meet" value="Колбаски гриль" onclick="addCurElement()">Колбаски гриль<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meet" value="Салями" onclick="addCurElement()">Салями<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="meet" value="Ветчина" onclick="addCurElement()">Ветчина<br>
```

Нужно при нажатии на какой-то из этих инпутов, чтобы функция или сборщик собирала значение этой кнопки( то есть value) и передавало в элемент списка выше по разметке.
То есть при нажатии например "Колбасок гриль", это значение передавалось методу который запишет это в список как элемент списка. Нужно на чистом Javascript.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function addCurElement(){ 
  var newli = document.createElement('li'); 
  var addElem = document.getElementsByClassName("meet"); 
  var add = document.createTextNode(addElem); 
  newli.appendChild(add);
  document.getElementById("curElements").appendChild(newli); 
}
```

Comment: ничего непонятно.

Comment: Посмотри скрин пожалуйста. Нужно к примеру при нажатии на "Ветчину" чтобы она передавала значение в поле "Выбранные элементы"

Comment: А в целом вопрос конкретнее можно задать. Как определить на какой класс мы нажимаем , чтобы его потом вытянуть?

Comment: console.log( $(this).val() );

Comment: Напишите код который у вас есть

Comment: function addCurElement(){
    
    var newli = document.createElement('li');
    var addElem = document.getElementsByClassName("meet");
    var add = document.createTextNode(addElem);    

   newli.appendChild(add); 
      
document.getElementById("curElements").appendChild(newli);
}

Comment: Не сюда, в вопрос, HTML, CSS, JS

Comment: не `"meet"`, а `"meat"`

Comment: Добавил ваш код, с checkbox все работает.  @RedLionHeart  В следующий раз сразу добавляйте свой код.  Иначе сами видите что бывает когда вопрос без вашего кода.

Answer (score 1):

На JavaScript

Файл: myscript.js

```js
function myFunction(el){  
  var textarea = document.getElementById("list");  
   
  
  Element.prototype.remove = function() {
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
  }
  NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
      for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
              this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
          }
      }
  }
  
  var  html = "\n" + "<li id='"+el.value+"'>"+el.value+"</li>"
  if (el.checked == true){ 
  
    textarea.innerHTML +=  html; 
    
  }else{   
      document.body.querySelectorAll('[id="'+el.value+'"]')[0].remove(); 
  }
   
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width:100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="list"></div>

<ul class="click">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product1" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="Колбаса">Колбаса<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="product2" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="Сыр">Сыр<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="product3" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="Лапша">Лапша<br>
</ul>

 
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Update 0.0.1

```js
function myFunction(el){  
  var textarea = document.getElementById("curElements");  
   
  
  Element.prototype.remove = function() {
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
  }
  NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
      for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
              this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
          }
      }
  }
  
  var  html = "\n" + "<li id='"+el.value+"'>"+el.value+"</li>"
  if (el.checked == true){ 
  
    textarea.innerHTML +=  html; 
    
  }else{   
      document.body.querySelectorAll('[id="'+el.value+'"]')[0].remove(); 
  }
   
}
```

```css
*{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "segoe ui light", sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    body{
        background: url(../image/back.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
    #flex{
        display:flex;
    }
    #vybor{
        width: 35%;
        height: 250px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 1.5%;
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        text-align: center;
        
    }
    #price{
       padding: 1%;
       
        font-size: 1.8em;
    }
    .ingredients{
        width: 25%;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        padding-left: 8%;
        line-height: 1.5;
        
        
    }
    #pizza{ 
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #2e5f0f;  
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        transform-origin: center;
        margin-left:60%;

       
    }

    .one{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-image: url(../image/1.png);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    .two{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-image: url(../image/2.png);
        left: 150px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .three{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 0px;
        background-image: url(../image/3.png);
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    .four{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-image: url(../image/4.png);
        left: 150px;
        top:150px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
 

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

</head>

<body>
   
    <div id="pad"><div id="vybor">
    Выбранные элементы: 
    <ul id = "curElements">
      asdasd  
    </ul>   
    </div>
    <div id = "pizza">
    <div class="inPizza one"></div>
    <div class="inPizza two"></div>
    <div class="inPizza three"></div>
    <div class="inPizza four"></div></div>
    
    <div id="price">Цена: <span>0</span> BYR</div>
        
    </div>
    <div id = "flex">
    <div class ="ingredients base"><h2>Основа для пиццы: </h2><br>
    <input type="radio" class ="base" value="Чесночная"> Чесночная <br>
    <input type="radio" class ="base" value="Томатная"> Томатная <br>
    <input type="radio" class ="base" value="Барбекю"> Барбекю <br>
    </div>
    <div class ="ingredients"><h2>Мясная начинка:</h2><br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="meat" value="Колбаски гриль" onclick="addCurElement()">Колбаски гриль<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="meat" value="Салями" onclick="addCurElement()">Салями<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="meat" value="Ветчина" onclick="addCurElement()">Ветчина<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="meat" value="Карбонат">Карбонат<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="meat" value="Бекон">Бекон<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="meat" value="Сервелат">Сервелат<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="meat" value="Курица<">Курица<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="meat" value="Телятина">Телятина<br>
    
    </div>
    <div class ="ingredients"><h2>Морская начинка:</h2><br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="fish" value="Креветки">Креветки<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="fish" value="Лосось">Лосось<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="fish" value="Мидии">Мидии<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="fish" value="Кальмар">Кальмар<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="fish" value="Крабовое мясо">Крабовое мясо<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="fish" value="Тунец">Тунец<br>
    </div>
    <div class ="ingredients"><h2>Соус:</h2><br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="sauce" value="Кисло-сладкий">Кисло-сладкий<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="sauce" value="Барбекю">Барбекю<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="sauce" value="Чесночный">Чесночный<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="sauce" value="Карри">Карри<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"  class="sauce" value="Терияки">Терияки<br>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/script.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: мне три Сыра с Лапшой

Comment: @Igor, ешь что дают :-D

Comment: а как насчёт снятия галочек?? Значение стоило бы убирать?

Comment: @SeeSharp да, стоило бы

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, что не "жри"!

Comment: @Igor, ну это как-то не вежливо :-D

Comment: Хз, там такого не написано :)

Comment: А если в раздельных документах сохранять, то не работает. index.html:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:13)

Comment: <head><script src="/script/myscript.js"> </script></head>

Comment: @Даниил дело не в подключении скрипта. я вкинул эту функцию в свой js. но он все равно не работает. Скинул полностью свой html/css документ. помогите пожалуйста сделать правильно js как я описал

Comment: @SeeSharp обновил